# OAuth2 server-side flow or client-flow for Facebook login on iOS app

Tags: ios, django, facebook, oauth

I'm coding an API with *Django + DRF* and my client is an iOS app. My users need to be able to authenticate with Facebook.

My initial thought was implementing the **client-side flow**, send the access token via https to my backend, retrieve the user info with that token and register/login the user with my back end and it seems this approach is the most popular since it's easier to implement using Facebook iOS SDK.

Is there any security gain by using the **server-side flow** instead?

But I'm not sure about the implementation of the server side flow. My understanding is that there would be a link to the third party OAuth endpoint (does it need to be a web view or it could be a link to Facebook native app?) with the redirection URI embedded (the app custom URL? something like *MyApp://...*? Am I right?). The ressource owner would authenticate and be redirected to the client (the app). The iOS app would then get the access code from the URL and send the access code to the back end. The back end then uses its id and secret along that code to get the user access token (so it's never handled by the client).

Wouldn't that work?

Does it worth it security-wise?

In a mobile app, doesn't it makes most sense to use the client-side flow?

I understand that tokens gotten with the client side flow are in most cases short-lived (depends on the provider), but this is not really a problem since Facebook provides an endpoint to trade short lived tokens for long lived ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Which is more likely to be compromised and have an attacker able to spy on the token exchange? Your server? Or the mobile client?

Comment: The client, of course. But the point is, Facebook really promotes the use of their SDK and the client side flow seems to be wide spread. Moreover, the client side flow seems more natural to me since even the tools I'll be using (e.g. Python-Social-Auth) offer tools to facilitate this flow, like the fuction register_by_access_token.

Comment: Right, so what's the odds that someone who uses your app already had another app that's using Facebook's client side OAuth? If it's already high, then I'd say the risk of your using the client side OAuth is not more than they're already exposing themselves to. If Facebook recommend a certain way, you can bet people are using it, so I'd say join the pack and use it to. Just my 2¢.

Comment: You comfort me with my choice haha I have the same opinion.